# I can't build a project(Android studio) ProjectConfigurationException

Tags: android, gradle

Good day, I can not build a project, after upgrading the studio to version 3.4. Here is my `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true  // this line will solve this problem
        applicationId "com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the error message:

> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred
>   configuring project ':app'.   at
>
> org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:654)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:132)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:195)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:157)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$2.execute(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:116)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find
>   support-compat.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/27.1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.jar
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:27)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:324)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:274)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveArtifact(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:136)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:168)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:155)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:135)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:934)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:658)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:658)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveConfiguration(DependencyManager.java:378)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:281)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createVariantData$3(VariantManager.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:603)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:793)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:469)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:263)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
>     ... 80 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find support-compat.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1). Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/27.1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.jar

try updating from:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2"
```

to:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0"
```

because that is why repository `google()` is not known in the first place.

Comment: You beat me to it! :)

Comment: I have it in build.gradle for project